# How do I combine data from 3 different Access tables into one master table?

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 access tables with information from the past 3 years. There are tons of the same records in each but there are also unique records in each.

2 tables have the same unique primary key (ID) while the 3rd table has a different set of unique IDs

How do I combine and select all the unique ID's into one master table? Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure Access supports union and union all, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I understand where the overlaps occur and not, but try this:

```
select ID
into All_Id
from (
  select ID from Table1
  union
  select ID from Table2
  union all
  select ID from Table3
)
```

This presupposes that Table1 and Table2 might share some IDs, and you only want them listed once, but Table3 doesn't have any overlaps.

Truth be told, there is no harm in making them all `union`, other than maybe having the query run slower.

Answer (score 1):

If you want unique IDs, use a UNION query. If you want everything, use a UNION ALL.

UNION = no dupes 
UNION ALL = returns all records including dupes

The Access engine supports union queries but you have to manually write the union query in the SQL view. Design view is not available.

Depending on how much data you have from the past three years, the UNION might take some time and may even blow up a few times. I'd make a back up copy first just in case.

If you want purely unique IDs and a new table, here's what I would do:

1.) Write your union query.

```
SELECT ID FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID FROM Table2
...
```

2.) Save the query.

3.) Create a make table query (to select and combine all unique IDs into a presumably new master table).

4.) Run the make table query. The new table will be created.

Hope that helps. Let us know how you make out!

Comment: +1 this is definitely an Access-centric way of doing it